# Why do I get null pointer exception for one sceanrio but not a similar sceanrio?

Tags: java, android, listview

The issue that I'm finding confusing is two similar situations both can be described as:-

From within an activity with a ListView I click on an Item which starts another activity to edit that item. Within the secondary activity, after editing the item and saving the changes to a database, I then need to refresh the ListView by swapping the cursor.

In one I use the following (this works without a null pointer) :-

```
    Cursor csr = shopperdb.getProductsperAisle(aisleid);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.aapts_layout);
    ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.aaptslv100);
    ProductsPerAisleCursorAdapter adapter = (ProductsPerAisleCursorAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
    adapter.swapCursor(csr);
    finish();
```

- The code above is in the activity named **ProductUsageEdit** which uses **activity_productusage_edit.xml** and has this set as the ContentView.
- ListView **aaptslv100** is in **aapts_layout** defined in **activity_shop_add.xml** Activity **AddProductToShopActivity** sets aapts_layout as the ContentView. This activity starts the **ProductUsageEdit** activity, when an item in the ListView **aaptslv100** is clicked.
- **R.id.aapts_layout** is the ID of the primary layout, **R.id.aaptslv100** being the ID of the ListView in that layout. This code is invoked via a button's OnClickListener.

The other scenario, if using the equivalent ie getting the initial activitity's View from the layout ID and then getting the ListView's ID via that V; issues a nullpointer exception (still results in the ListView being refreshed) ie using :-

```
    View v = findViewById(R.id.aslbc_layout);
    ListView callerListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.aslbclv01);
    ....
```

Rather in the second sceanrio, to not get the null pointer exception I code :-

```
    Cursor csr = shopperdb.getShopsAsCursor();
    ListView callerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.aslbclv01);
    ShopsCursorAdapter calleradapter = (ShopsCursorAdapter)callerListView.getAdapter();
    calleradapter.changeCursor(csr);
```

- The code above is in **ShopAddActivity**, uses ListView **aslbclv01** from activity **ShopListByCursorActivity** in layout **aslbc_layout** from **activity_shop_list_by_cursor.xml**.

(Obviously the Listview is different as are the adapters used and the cursor obtained, ps finish() is coded just a little later outside of the If clause that this code is within).

If I try using the equivalent of this in the first scenario, then I get a null pointer exception (again the ListView then gets refreshed).

What I'd like is a standard method that would suite both and other similar situations. I'd also greatly appreciate some understanding as to why I appear to need to use different methods for what is basically the same scenario.

---

*(added)*

Thinking about this a bit more, there is a difference between the two scenarios;

The first sceanrio's called secondary activity has a more complex layout. In that it is a LinearLayout with nested LinearLayouts and then the Text/EditViews.

The second scenario uses a RelativeLayout under which the views all reside.

Could this perhaps be the need to get the originating Layout ID?

However, if that is the case, it would still leave me pondering why `View v = findViewById(<orginatingLayout>)` sets v as null in the less complex second scenario. Perhaps findByView is viewtype sensitive?

Comment: Did you try notifyDataSetChanged() method instead of swapping cursor?

Comment: @Nolly J I have tried that previously, although I'm much more comfortable swapping cursor. The issue isn't with the ListView being updated, that is happening (even with a null pointer exception). The issue is with the methodology/techniques and likely a deeper understanding of the scope of Views and perhaps the part of xml resources (I think anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous attempts at getting the ListView's adapter (required for `swapCursor()`, `changeCursor()` or `notifyDataSetChanged()`). This included attempts at passing the object via the Intent (serialization issues). I tried **onResume** with a flag indicating what should cause onResume to trigger. So for now, at least, trying to retrieve another activity's layout elements is simply too difficult for my level of experience.

For the first scenario (will look at the second and others).

My final code, at least the bulk of it, which I believe can be adopted/adapted as a standard by myself, is:-

No code at all in the secondary activity that updates the data (in regard to swapping the cursror).

In the primary activity from which the second activity is called :-

```
public final static int RESUMESTATE_NOTHING = 0;
public final static int RESUMESTATE_PRODUCTUSAGEEDIT = 1;
public final static String[] RESUMESTATE_DESCRIPTIONS = {"Nothing","ProductUsageEdit"};

public int resume_state = RESUMESTATE_NOTHING;
public long currentshopid = -1;
public long currentaisleid = -1;
public ProductsPerAisleCursorAdapter currentppaca;

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(Constants.LOG," onResume invoked in " + THIS_ACTIVITY + "-  Current State=" + resume_state + "-"+RESUMESTATE_DESCRIPTIONS[resume_state]);
    switch (resume_state) {
        case RESUMESTATE_NOTHING: {
            break;
        }
        case RESUMESTATE_PRODUCTUSAGEEDIT: {
            Cursor csr = shopperdb.getProductsperAisle(currentaisleid);
            currentppaca.swapCursor(csr);
            resume_state = RESUMESTATE_NOTHING;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

With the following in the respective onClickListener that calls the secondactivity:-

```
resume_state = RESUMESTATE_PRODUCTUSAGEEDIT;
currentppaca = adapterpl;
currentaisleid = aisleid;
currentshopid = shopid;
```

Answer (score 1):

To succesfully find a view instance by id, first you must make sure that correct layout has been set for `Activity`/`Fragment` instance. `findViewById()` of Activity, AFAIK, finds child view of top parent node who has same id as given id. It does not recursively find view in nested `ViewGroup`. `ViewGroup` is descendant of View and acts as a container of one or more views. `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` are few example of a ViewGroup.

So if you have following layout:

#### res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context="com.juhara.demo.intent1.MainActivity" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_start"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/str_btn1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and inside Activity's `OnCreate()`, you call

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

then you can succesfully get `Button` instance by calling `findViewById()` of Activity

```
Button abutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
```

However if you have nested layout, for example

#### res/layout/activity_main2.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <RelativeLayout 
       android:id="@+id/button_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
        <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn_start"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/str_btn1" />
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

then following code will make `abutton` set to null.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
Button abutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
```

To properly get `Button` instance you have to find parent node of Button first and then use it to find view.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
View button_container = findViewById(R.id.button_container);
Button abutton = (Button) button_container.findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
```

Comment: That's a really good description. However, the second scenario appears to contradict that. That is unless relatives (brothers/sisters) comes into play. That is in the second scenario the ContentView is not the same (nor in the first) as the view instance is in a different activity/class. It's a little like how would you find main's button from the main2 activity (assuming that you haven't). However, in my second scenario, the shorter Viewgroup-less FindViewByID works across activities. I will change the question to include activity names and the layout sources.